# I want to pull elements in list to display on HTML

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem with a Flask function for returning elements with the index of an element in a list outputting to Html using multiple for loops. 
Sample of data:[ant,box,cat,dog,eat,fat]
index:[[a,n,t],[b,o,x],[c,a,t],[d,o,g],[f,a,t]]    listnew:[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]..]

python.py

```
sum=0
for i in range(0,len(index)):
  for j in range(0,len(index[i])):
     list_new[sum] = index[i][j]
     sum+=1

return render_template('htmlfile.html',Elements = zip(index,list_new))
```

htmlfile.html

```
{% for index,list_new in Elements %}
   {{index}}
   {{index_list[0]}}
   {{index_list[1]}}
   {{index_list[2]}}
   {{index_list[3]}}
{% endfor %}
```

but It wasn’t what I had hoped for. 
I want to show 
a
1
2
3
4
5
b
6
7
8
9
10

thank for help

Comment: What output do you get instead? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Thank you for answer.Now I'm edit my question

Comment: What are you expecting  with this line: list_new[sum] = index[i][j]